# SQL Job get stuck on a simple Select into vaiables query

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2017, sql-server-agent

I have an issue that I please need help in trying to resolve as its really becoming a bit pain.

I have some Jobs that monitor our systems for calls stuck and it's getting stuck (the irony is not lost on me).
Basically it's 2 stored procedures that run every 30s.
**SP_A** : Inserts call data from the call tables on various customer DB's using linked servers and lots of dynamic code but works fantastically and is efficient etc.

**SP_B** : Checks and updates the Calls that get inserted. Alerts us or archives them etc based on a bunch of rules etc.

In SP_B, there is a very simple select query that the job is getting stuck on once there is a moderate load on the process (It's at about >100 calls being monitored/processed). This is not a given, as there are times when it will process a big load absolutely fine. So I think my main problem is trying to reproduce it is nearly impossible.

**The Issue:**
Occasionally, someone will notice the dashboard that runs off this system is stuck or not refreshing. I will immediately go to the job running SP_B, and see that it's been stuck for a while (sometimes days). Upon running Adam Mechanics sp_whoisactive I can see that it is sitting on this piece of code and just not moving on :

```
SELECT @CallID = CallID, @CustomerID = [Mon_CustomerID], @CustomerDatabase = [DatabaseName],@AGNodeName = [AGNodeName], @SystemName = [System]
    , @Hist_Done = Mon_Done, @OLD_Incomplete = Mon_Incomplete, @HistQueued = Mon_Queued, @OLD_CPM = Mon_CPM, @VOC_Mon_AutoFix = [VOC_Mon_Call_AutoFix]
    , @VOC_Mon_Call_AlertMin = [VOC_Mon_Call_AlertMin], @VOC_Mon_Call = [VOC_Mon_Call], @Mon_Status = VMC.[Mon_Status], @CallStatus = [Status], @Mon_LastChecked_EST = [Mon_LastChecked_EST]
    ,@CurDone = Mon_Done,@CurIncomplete = Mon_Incomplete,@CurQueue = Mon_Queued,@CurAvgCPM = Mon_CPM
    FROM [dbo].[Monitor_Call] VMC WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Dim_Customer] DC WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Mon_CustomerID] = DC.[CustomerID]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CustomerSettings] CS WITH (NOLOCK) ON DC.[CustomerID] = CS.[CustomerID]
    WHERE ID = @ID
```

For some context, 
the Monitor_Call table is the table with the calls in that are currently being monitored. So let's say it can have anything from 100-500 calls in when the SP gets stuck. Essentially an insignificant amount though.

The Dim_Customer and Customersettings tables each have approx 100 rows in. Again, insignificant. I run this query in basically 0.00s manually or while profiling it.

The query is the first step in a loop, that loops through all the calls. Could that be part of the issue? Im potentially thinking maybe the row it's trying to select has already been archived and therefore no longer exists?
The Archiving process happens in SP_B as well so it should not unless there is in some way more that one instance running at a time?

Does anyone have any ideas as to why I am having issues with this one query?
This is what i see in sp_whoisactive
[image: sp_whoisactive]

Here is the majority of the Procedure. I have stripped out some parts just to make it shorter and show the login, the parts that are irrelevant to the logic.

```
ALTER   PROCEDURE [dbo].[spMonitor_Call_Processing] 
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @AGNodeName nvarchar(50);
DECLARE @CustomerDatabase nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @Query nvarchar(max) = '';
DECLARE @CustomerID int;
DECLARE @CallID int;
DECLARE @CallStatus varchar(30);
DECLARE @ID int;
DECLARE @_Mon_Call bit;
DECLARE @Mon_Status varchar(30);
DECLARE @Mon_LastChecked_EST datetime;
DECLARE @_Mon_AutoFix bit;
DECLARE @_Mon_Call_Status_AutoFix bit;
DECLARE @_Mon_Comment NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SendNotif bit = 'False';
DECLARE @_Mon_Call_AlertMin int;
DECLARE @LatestDate datetime;
DECLARE @SystemName nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @Body NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TableHead NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TableData NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TableData2 NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TableTail NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SQLToRun NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @SendEmail bit = 0;
DECLARE @Hist_Done decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @OLD_Incomplete decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @HistQueued decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @OLD_CPM decimal(18,2);
DECLARE @Mon_StuckType int;
DECLARE @5MinTable TABLE
    (
        [Type] varchar(150)
        ,Total decimal(18,2)
        ,AvgValue decimal(18,2)
        ,MaxValue decimal(18,2)
    );
DECLARE @HistTable TABLE
    (
        [Type] varchar(150)
        ,Total decimal(18,2)
        ,AvgValue decimal(18,2)
        ,MaxValue decimal(18,2)
    );
PRINT 'Update Records'
EXEC [sp_Monitor_Call_Update] --This Updates all the calls in the monitoring table with the latest values
EXEC [Monitor_CallActivity_Update] --Selects values into Temp Table for Dashboard chart

--Some Batch Status Updates are done here (not included)

SET @ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM [dbo].[Monitor_Call] VMC WITH (NOLOCK)   WHERE [VMC].[Mon_Status] IN (1,2));
--Loop thourhg calls in table
WHILE @ID IS NOT NULL
BEGIN

    DECLARE @CurDone decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @CurIncomplete decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @CurQueue decimal(18,2)
    DECLARE @CurAvgCPM decimal(18,2)

    SELECT @CallID = CallID, @CustomerID = [Mon_CustomerID], @CustomerDatabase = [DatabaseName],@AGNodeName = [AGNodeName], @SystemName = [System]
    , @Hist_Done = Mon_Done, @OLD_Incomplete = Mon_Incomplete, @HistQueued = Mon_Queued, @OLD_CPM = Mon_CPM, @_Mon_AutoFix = [_Mon_Call_AutoFix]
    , @_Mon_Call_AlertMin = [_Mon_Call_AlertMin], @_Mon_Call = [_Mon_Call], @Mon_Status = VMC.[Mon_Status], @CallStatus = [Status], @Mon_LastChecked_EST = [Mon_LastChecked_EST]
    ,@CurDone = Mon_Done,@CurIncomplete = Mon_Incomplete,@CurQueue = Mon_Queued,@CurAvgCPM = Mon_CPM
    FROM [dbo].[Monitor_Call] VMC WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Dim_Customer] DC WITH (NOLOCK) ON [Mon_CustomerID] = DC.[CustomerID]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CustomerSettings] CS WITH (NOLOCK) ON DC.[CustomerID] = CS.[CustomerID]
    WHERE ID = @ID;

    IF @CallStatus = 'Done'
    BEGIN
        CONTINUE
    END

    IF @_Mon_Call = 'True'
    BEGIN

        UPDATE [dbo].[Monitor_Call] SET [Mon_Status] = 2 WHERE ID = @ID AND Mon_Status = 1;

        SET @Query = '[' + @AGNodeName + '].[' + @CustomerDatabase + '].[dbo].[sp_GetLatestDate] @LatestDate OUTPUT;'
        PRINT @Query
        EXEC sp_executesql @Query, N'@LatestDate datetime out', @LatestDate OUT;
        PRINT 'LatestDate : ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(50), @LatestDate)

        IF @Mon_LastChecked_EST < DATEADD(Minute, 1, @LatestDate) OR @Mon_LastChecked_EST IS NULL
        BEGIN

            DELETE FROM @5MinTable;

            --Get Current Data
                SET @Query = ';WITH Calls AS
                (
                    SELECT [idCallQueue], [CallDate], [Active], [Status], CQ.[Result] AS CallResult,[Channel], [DurationSecs] AS Duration, [StartTime], SC.[Result] AS SysResult, [ResultCode]
                    FROM [' + @AGNodeName + '].[' + @CustomerDatabase + '].[dbo].[CallQueue] CQ WITH (NOLOCK)
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN [' + @AGNodeName + '].[' + @CustomerDatabase + '].[dbo].[SysCalls] SC WITH (NOLOCK)
                    ON CQ.[idCallQueue] = SC.[CallID]
                    WHERE idcallqueue > ' + CONVERT(varchar(50),@CallID) + ' AND [CQ].[System] = ''' + @SystemName + '''
                )
                ,CPM AS
                (
                    SELECT FORMAT([StartTime],''yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm'') AS [Date], COUNT([idCallQueue]) AS ''Calls''
                    FROM Calls C
                    WHERE C.[Status] = ''Done''
                    GROUP BY FORMAT([StartTime],''yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm'')
                )
                    SELECT ''Done'' AS [Type], COUNT([idCallQueue]) AS Total, AVG(Duration) AS AvgValue, MAX(Duration) AS MaxValue
                    FROM Calls C
                    WHERE C.[Status] = ''Done''
                UNION
                    SELECT ''Queued'', COUNT([idCallQueue]), AVG(DATEDIFF(minute,CallDate,''' + CONVERT(varchar(50),@LatestDate) + ''')) AS AvgDuration, MAX(DATEDIFF(minute,CallDate,''' + CONVERT(varchar(50),@LatestDate) + ''')) AS MaxDuration
                    FROM Calls C
                    WHERE C.[Status] = ''Queued''
                UNION
                    SELECT ''Incomplete'', COUNT([idCallQueue]), AVG(DATEDIFF(minute,CallDate,''' + CONVERT(varchar(50),@LatestDate) + ''')) AS AvgDuration, MAX(DATEDIFF(minute,CallDate,''' + CONVERT(varchar(50),@LatestDate) + ''')) AS MaxDuration
                    FROM Calls C
                    WHERE C.[Status] NOT IN (''Done'', ''Queued'')
                UNION
                    SELECT ''CPM'', NULL, AVG(Calls), MAX(Calls)
                    FROM CPM;'
                    PRINT @Query

                INSERT INTO @5MinTable ([Type],Total,AvgValue, MaxValue)
                EXEC (@Query)

                SET @CallStatus = (SELECT Status FROM [dbo].[Monitor_Call] VMC WHERE [VMC].[ID]  = @ID)
                IF @CallStatus = 'Done'
                BEGIN
                    CONTINUE
                END

                SET @Query = NULL;

                SET @CurQueue = (SELECT Total FROM @5MinTable WHERE Type = 'Queued');--
                SET @CurAvgCPM = (SELECT AvgValue FROM @5MinTable WHERE Type = 'CPM');--
                DECLARE @CurMaxCPM decimal(18,2) = (SELECT MaxValue FROM @5MinTable WHERE Type = 'CPM');--
                DECLARE @MaxDuration decimal(18,2) = (SELECT MaxValue FROM @5MinTable WHERE Type = 'Done');
                DECLARE @Mon_CurSysQueue int = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Monitor_Call] VC WHERE VC.[Mon_CustomerID]  = @CustomerID AND VC.[System] = @SystemName AND STATUS = 'Queued')
                DECLARE @Mon_OtherSysQueue int = ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dbo].[Monitor_Call] VC WHERE VC.[Mon_CustomerID]    = @CustomerID AND VC.[System] <> @SystemName AND STATUS = 'Queued')
                SET @MaxDuration = @MaxDuration + (@MaxDuration*0.5);

                SET @CurIncomplete = (SELECT Total FROM @5MinTable WHERE Type = 'Incomplete');--
                SET @CurDone = (SELECT Total FROM @5MinTable WHERE Type = 'Done');--
                DECLARE @CurCallDuration decimal(18,2) = (SELECT DATEDIFF(second,CallDate,@LatestDate) FROM [dbo].[Monitor_Call] WHERE ID =  @ID);

                UPDATE [dbo].[Monitor_Call] 
                SET Mon_Done = @CurDone,
                Mon_Incomplete = @CurIncomplete,
                Mon_Queued = @CurQueue,
                Mon_CPM = @CurAvgCPM,
                Mon_LastChecked_EST = GETDATE()
                WHERE @CustomerID = [Mon_CustomerID] AND @SystemName = [System]

            END --IF @Mon_LastChecked_EST < DATEADD(Minute, 1, @LatestDate)

            --Some Call Status Updates are done here (not included)

            EXEC [sp_Monitor_Call_Update]
            EXEC [Monitor_CallActivity_Update]


        END --@_Mon_Call

        SET @ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM [dbo].[Monitor_Call] VMC WITH (NOLOCK)   WHERE ID > @ID AND [VMC].[Mon_Status] IN (1,2))
END --End Call Loop

SET @ID = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM [dbo].[Monitor_Call] VMC WITH (NOLOCK)   WHERE [VMC].[Mon_Status] IN (3) AND [Mon_ProposedSQL] IS NOT NULL);


--Construct and Send Email for Calls that are stuck.

END -- Procedure Closure
```

Thank you very much for your time and assistance.

Comment: Are you sure the query is hanging? Maybe you always see the query on some next loop step. Sort of infinite loop?

Comment: Are you on the latest service pack?  If not, I would start there.  You'll eventually need to be on the latest SP to be able to install the latest security updates.

Comment: 16 billion reads sounds like a lot for 100-500 rows of data. Something is awry here and I'm guessing it's the looping part that you're not showing.

Comment: I added the majority of the code for the procedure. Thank you. I am also on the latest SP too : 14.0.1000.169

Comment: @DenisRubashkin I have added a loop max counter and will see if that resolves the issue but i am not holding my breath :)